# Visible seam in texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to improve my texturing. Here is a model I'm doing for a game. This is the best way to unwrap it to bake from a higher poly without having the normal colors collide right? When I go to texture with Substance or Quixel, the seam is highly visible. Is there a way around this?

[image]

[image]

Blend file: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3756/

Comment: How many pixels of bake margin do you have?

Comment: Here is a preview render I did of the bake at 24 px margin with textures Quixel spit out. https://gyazo.com/60d65050f2b14ff7a9e60ee2547ff987

Comment: Could you post a .blend, with textures packed, using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: There you go. I added the blend file to the end of my post.

Comment: I took a look, and in your bake settings Selected-to-Active was not checked. Try selecting first the high-poly mesh, then the low-poly object, and then baking with Selected-to-Active enabled.

Comment: I bake the maps in Substance and then texture the low poly.

Comment: Oh, well that changes things. I don't have Substance, (although I plan on getting it soon), so there is a big question mark for me in your workflow there. Maybe somebody else here knows. One last idea is, make sure there isn't some discrepancy being caused by modifiers.

Comment: You got me thinking about Substance Painter again and I happened to be watching a tutorial on the basics of it. [The tutorial author said that if backface culling is on while you're painting you can end up with seams showing.](https://youtu.be/Lv-ed9V0dE4?t=2m58s) I'm not sure if this also applies to baking or not, but It figured I'd mention it to you.